# How to delay an alert?

Tags: jquery, delay, alert

I'm trying to delay an alert but can't get it to work, it always pops up when #foo is hovered over and is increasing in size:

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
 $(this).animate({width :'400px'}, 'slow');
},
function() {
 $(this).delay(2000).animate({width :'40px'}, 'slow');
alert('Im an alert message');
});
```

but I want it to show only after #foo has decreased back to original state ...

Answer (score 6):

How about Using a callback ??

```
$('#foo').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '400px'
    }, 'slow');
}, function () {
    $(this).delay(2000).animate({
        width: '40px'
    }, 'slow', function () { //callback function, which runs very next to .animate()
        alert('Im an alert message');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in a callback.  This is a function that will be called when the animation is complete:

```
$(this).delay(2000).animate({width :'40px'}, 'slow', function(){
    alert("I'm an alert message");
});
```

See the [`animate` API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you want to use a callback on the animate function?

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(this).delay(2000).animate({width :'40px'}, 
    'slow',
    function () {
        alert('Im an alert message');
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the setTimeout function: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
$('#foo').hover(function() {
 setTimeout(function(){$(this).animate({width :'400px'}, 'slow');}, 3000);
}
```

The above code should delay for 3 seconds.

Comment: This has nothing to do with delaying the alert